# Calling Flash function using ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2, externalinterface

I'm having trouble calling a function through the use of ExternalInterface.

First off, here's the HTML/JS side:

```
<p align="right">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="camera.swf" 
width="200" height="200" align="right" id="camSWF">
<param name="movie" value="camera.swf" align="right" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
</object></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashObj = document.getElementById('camSWF');
document.onmousemove = setMouseXY;
function setMouseXY(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    flashObj.rotateCam(x, y, $(document).width(), $(document).height());
}
</script>
```

And secondly, here is the ActionScript 2 code:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('setMouseXY', null, rotateCam);
function rotateCam(mouseX, mouseY, docWidth, docHeight)
{
    // DO STUFF
}
```

As far as I can see, everything should work, but obviously I'm missing something.

Whenever the mouse event fires on the HTML page, I get this error in Firebug:

```
flashObj.rotateCam is not a function: 
flashObj.rotateCam(x, y, $(document).width(), $(document).height());
```

I'm quite stuck. Perhaps it's some security thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('setMouseXY', null, rotateCam);
```

This statement adds "rotateCam" as the callback function for "setMouseXY". So "setMouseXY" is the function that has to be called from javascript.

```
function setMouseXY(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
   var y = e.pageY;
   flashObj.setMouseXY(x, y, $(document).width(), $(document).height());
}
```

Comment: Or in actionscript you can use
`ExternalInterface.addCallback('rotateCam', null, rotateCam);`
to work with the current javascript code.

Comment: Hm, thanks for that. I probably should read code a little more carefully next time